# heidisql error 1064: Syntax related

Tags: mysql, sql, heidisql

I'm very new to sql. I studied in Uni but now have completely forgotten and starting over again. Ive added another joined table:

```
SELECT bx-book-ratings.isbn, bx-books.title, bx-users.location, bx-book-ratings.book-rating
FROM `bx-book-ratings`
INNER JOIN `bx-users`
ON `bx-book-ratings`.user-id=`bx-users`.user-id
INNER JOIN `bx-books`
ON `bx-book-ratings`.isbn=`bx-books`.isbn
```

And im getting an error 1054 ; unknown column name 'bx' in field list.

Comment: You need to delimit identifiers including dashes. ANSI SQL way `"bx-users"` and `"bx-users".location`. But MySQL probably wants back-ticks instead of double quotes?

Comment: So any terms or fields that require a dash must be put into back ticks or double quotes? Does this apply to the columns ive selected at top?  SELECT bx-books-rating.isbn, bx-users.location, bx-book-ratings.book-rating
FROM 'bx-Book-Ratings'
INNER JOIN 'bx-users';
ON 'bx-book-rating'.user-id='bx-users'.user-id

Comment: Yes, a dash is not allowed, use underscores instead.

Comment: Ok ive updated it to this and still getting a syntax error --SELECT 'bx-books-rating'.isbn, 'bx-users'.location, 'bx-book-ratings'.book-rating
FROM 'bx-Book-Rating'
INNER JOIN 'bx-users';
ON 'bx-book-rating'.user-id='bx-users'.user-id

Comment: You should get **Incorrect syntax near 'bx-Book-Rating'**. If you don't, you have a serious problem with your working environment. Also, HeidiSQL is just a tool to connect to MySQL Server. HeidiSQL couldn't care less about your SQL syntax; MySQL Server, however, does.

Comment: You need to use back-tick ` and not single quote ' for table name... In fact the naming you have, you don't even need to use it.

Comment: Please close as current problem is different to everything listed above. To anyone reading l the solution to the table not being read was to use back-tick and not quotation.

Comment: Please do not crosspost the same question in different forums. See http://www.heidisql.com/forum.php?t=21056